# Algorithm for distributing

Tags: algorithm

You have a list of "people" Lp and another list of "food" Lf.

Each element in Lp wants one or more of the elements in Lf, but can only recieve one.

How should be an algorithm to decide which element in Lf give to each element in Lp (no need to distribute all Lf nor provide to all Lp). You are trying to maximize the number of Lp that has a Lf assigned that it wanted.

Comment: sounds like finding a maximum matching of a bipartite graph

Comment: Aka, [Stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by modelling the problem as a graph and solving for [maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) as follows:

1. Consider each person a node in a graph; let us call these p-nodes.
2. Consider each food another node in the same graph; let us call these f-nodes.
3. If person `a` likes food `b`, add an edge between *p_a* and *f_b*. Do this for each food that anyone likes. Each of these edges will have a capacity of 1.
4. Create a source node, I, that connects to each p-node. Since each person can eat at most 1 food, the edges from I to each p-node should also have a capacity of 1.
5. Create a sink node, O, that connects to each f-node. Since each food can be eaten by at most 1 person, these edges should also have a capacity of 1.
6. Run the [Edmonds-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithm (or any other max-flow algorithm); and look at the output. The edges from p-nodes to f-nodes used by the resulting max-flow network are the answer to the problem.

Notice that by changing the capacity of edges, you can accomodate variations to problem statement.